# Android : Overcome System.loadlibrary(); issue about  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkerror

Tags: android, pdf, android-ndk, apvpdf

I am working on APV pdf reader. I am facing `System.loadLibrary("pdfview2");` error. It's giving `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkerror`.
How to fix this issue? I installed Android-NDK also, but not getting how to load native libraries. Full confusion. Please suggest me a way to fix this issue.

```
09-26 12:51:44.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2537): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-26 12:51:44.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2537): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
09-26 12:51:44.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2537):     at cx.hell.android.pdfview.OpenFileActivity.getPDF(OpenFileActivity.java:541)
09-26 12:51:44.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2537):     at cx.hell.android.pdfview.OpenFileActivity.startPDF(OpenFileActivity.java:502)
09-26 12:51:44.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2537):     at cx.hell.android.pdfview.OpenFileActivity.onCreate(OpenFileActivity.java:219)
09-26 12:51:44.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2537):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-26 12:51:44.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2537):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
09-26 12:51:44.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2537):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
09-26 12:51:44.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2537):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-26 12:51:44.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2537):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
09-26 12:51:44.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2537):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-26 12:51:44.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2537):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-26 12:51:44.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2537):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-26 12:51:44.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2537):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-26 12:51:44.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2537):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-26 12:51:44.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2537):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-26 12:51:44.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2537):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-26 12:51:44.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2537):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-26 12:51:44.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2537): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load pdfview2: findLibrary returned null
09-26 12:51:44.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2537):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:429)
09-26 12:51:44.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2537):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
09-26 12:51:44.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2537):     at cx.hell.android.lib.pdf.PDF.<clinit>(PDF.java:25)
09-26 12:51:44.243: E/AndroidRuntime(2537):     ... 16 more
```

Hi i attached the log report .its giving :- Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load pdfview2: findLibrary returned null

Comment: it can be for a lot of reasons, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262440/how-to-resolve-the-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-in-ndk-in-android   
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862208/android-ndk-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror   
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626967/beginner-help-with-ndk-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror

Comment: hi.. here i am not getting how to and where to start modifying the APV reader. can you please suggest if you having any idea.

Comment: can you post your log, to try to specify the error..

Comment: hi i added the log report. please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have libpdfview2.so in your libs folder..

http://code.google.com/p/apv/issues/detail?id=42
[Android - 'Couldn't load Foo: findLibrary returned null'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11760284/android-couldnt-load-foo-findlibrary-returned-null)

Comment: links are helpfull ,but not getting exact procedure to for ndk build for APV reader.

Answer (score 3):

After building your project, look in the libs/ folder for the resulting .so.  If you're building for ARM, is there an armeabi or armeabi-v7a folder with your .so in it?  You can set the architectures you want to support in jni/Application.mk with the **APP_ABI** variable.

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86 mips
```

will build your library for all of the possible supported architectures.

Don't forget that Android's dynamic linker is dumb and won't load library dependencies automatically.  If you're using C++ code with gnustl_shared, for example, you'll need to load that before any libraries that are linked against it.

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("gnustl_shared");
    System.loadLibrary("a_cplusplus_library");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your supporting answer... here i am using APV PDF Reader. i didnt get proper documentaion also and first time i am using ndk. any detail procedure is there to,how to build project.? can you help me for this please...

Comment: +1 I wish I could give you a +10 because I've wasted an entire day trying to solve this problem and the solution was so simple: in jni/Application.mk add the line `APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86 mips`. It was only generating armeabi/liblibname.so, now it creates a folder for each architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for this failure, in my experience, is the presence of libs/armeabi and not libs/armeabi-v7a.  Copy the contents of libs/armeabi into a new folder named libs/armeabi-v7a.

Answer (score 0):

1- make sure name of native function Java_package_className_methodName

2- APP_ABI := all64 //defined in jni/Application.mk